# Click event attached to Checkbox doesn't work in mobile browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am in need of your help. I am having a difficult time with getting the
event handler making work in mobile

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8017

Click event attached to Checkbox/Radio item do work in desktop browser but doesn't work in mobile browser.

I have this piece of code which works fine on browser , but the events are not being captured on mobile

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event, data) {
alert('ss');
});

$(document).on('click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event, data) {
alert('ss');
});
```

which gets called on checkbox check and uncheck as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/34/

But this events are not being captured when using with mobile

(I am generating the above HTML dynamically) and i am using trigger.create and updatelayout also

could anybody please let me know why they aren't being captured in mobile

For your reference i am creating the HTML as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/35/

please let me know if there is any issue .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that actually works fine for me on mobile, though it may be browser dependent. however, a close mobile equivalent to `click` is `touchend` so how about

```
$(document).on('click touchend', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event, data) {
alert('ss');
});

$(document).on('click touchend', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event, data) {
alert('ss');
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events

Answer (score -1):

Try utilizing `touchstart` event

```
$(document).on('touchstart click', '.remove', function (e) {
    $("#addonsWrap").find("label.ui-checkbox-on").trigger('click', [1]);
});


$(document).on('touchstart click', '.ui-checkbox-off', function (event, data) {
    if(data !== undefined) return;

    var cost = $(this).data('cost');
    var totalcost = parseFloat($('.totalcost').text());
    totalcost = totalcost + cost;
    $('.totalcost').text(totalcost)
});


$(document).on('touchstart click', '.ui-checkbox-on', function (event, data) {

    if(data !== undefined) return;
    alert('ss');
    var cost = $(this).data('cost');
    var totalcost = parseFloat($('.totalcost').text());
    totalcost = totalcost - cost;
    $('.totalcost').text(totalcost)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/41/

Comment: thank you very much , i need to generate an apk  (Phonegap)and test this under android tab and let you know , but my concern is a similar issue is reported here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6649 and  i didn't understand the solution they reported for this (how to solve this)

Comment: Can utilize chrome / chromium browser ?

Comment: As i said this works under browser , so no issues under browser , but only on mobile.

Comment: @Kiran At chrome / chromium,  try navigate to link at post, open `console` -> select "Toggle emulation enabled." -> select "Emulate touch screen" -> click "Run" at jsfiddle panel -> check if `touchstart` event return expected results ?

Comment: I did as you mentioed your code works fine  but the code under previous fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/34/ also works know under Emulation Enabled under chrome console